# Statistical Estimation of Machine Learning Metrics

Tags: machine-learning, classification, confidence-interval, metric

Aloha Cross Validated,

In the context of binary classifiers we have a [number of metrics](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#) like accuracy, precision, recall, AUROC, F1, etc. To show robustness of a model we can gain a [confidence interval via a bootstrap](https://machinelearningmastery.com/confidence-intervals-for-machine-learning/). Personally I have had issues with bootstrapping done with small / imbalanced datasets. Sometimes the bootstrap population contains only one class and creates issues with the bootstrap. This is more likely in class imbalanced scenario like healthcare data.

I would like to know about easy / robust ways to make this process of obtaining a confidence interval for these ML metrics. [This package](https://github.com/jacobgil/confidenceinterval) computes analytic confidence intervals (that is, CIs in which we have a formula for the width) for a number of ML metrics. However, it does not have metrics like balanced accuracy

$$\texttt{balanced-accuracy} = \frac{1}{2}\left( \frac{TP}{TP + FN} + \frac{TN}{TN + FP}\right )$$

I am not sure what arithmetic operations we can do on different CIs. That is, the first term in =balanced-accuracy= is a ratio of true positives (which we may calculate the CI for) and the sum of true positive and true negatives. Hence this term includes a sum of confidence intervals and quotients of confidence intervals.

Also, have CIs been studied for notions of [Algorithmic fairness](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1908.09635.pdf?trk=public_post_comment-text)?

Please help me clarify if I am unclear.

Comment: Have you looked into a stratified bootstrap sample?  `R`'s bootstrap function allows you to guarantee a sample from a minority class in a bootstrap sample by using strata.  As a separate question, what is the purpose of calculating a confidence interval for a model fit diagnostic?  The normal interpretation of a confidence interval is that there is a true value for a parameter that describes the data generating process, and the confidence interval has a probability of containing that true value.

Comment: @RCarnell Thank you for your response. I have used stratified bootstrapping using Sklearn's resample function. However this does not allow me to use Scipy's bootstrap function which has BCa bootstrapping and parallelism implemented. My main concerns are efficiency as the dataset I use requires payment by the hour. Not to mention the speed is just nice overall.

I see a lot of papers publish CIs. Perhaps I am just doing what I see other people do. But I believe that CIs are able to display a type of robustness of the metric in a way that point estimates cannot.